# How to get value from the first UNION table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to populate the same [Company name] value from the first table(AS po) for the second table(AS pp) rows when [Product ID] is matched?

```
SELECT [Product ID], [Order Date], [Company Name], [Transaction], [Quantity]
FROM [Product Orders] AS po
LEFT JOIN [COMPANY] c ON c.id=po.company_id

UNION

SELECT [Product ID], [Creation Date], [Company Name], [Transaction], [Quantity]
FROM [Product Purchases] AS pp
```

To do this, the [Company name] value from the second table (AS pp) always be NULL, use INNER/LEFT JOIN will cause many duplicate rows.

UPDATE:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a60cd/10

```
select 
m.id AS 'Order ID', 
total AS 'Total', 
ROOM_NAME  AS 'Room Name', 
Item_ID AS 'Item ID',
Row_Type AS 'Row Type'

from ((
 select 
 m.id AS 'ORDER_ID',   
 room_name  AS 'ROOM_NAME', 
 NULL AS 'Item_ID',
'From Details' AS 'Row_Type'
from orders_master m 
left join order_details d ON m.id = d.order_id
left join store_rooms r ON d.room_id =r.id
Where room_id IS NOT NULL
) 
UNION ALL   
(
 select 
 m.id AS 'ORDER_ID',   
 NULL  AS 'ROOM_NAME', 
 item_id AS 'Item_ID',
 'From Inventory' AS 'Row_Type'
 from orders_master m 
 left join order_inventory i ON m.id = i.order_id 
 Where item_id IS NOT NULL
)) AS u
inner join orders_master m  ON m.id = u.order_id 
order by m.id, ROOM_NAME, item_id
```

From the example, I do not want to show [Room Name] as a NULL value.

Need some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You say you want to populate a column.  Shouldn't you be using an `update`?

Comment: you would expect many rows if you are showing each company that has purchased each product...?

Comment: We really need to see some sample data and the expected result here. It seems the query can be written in a totally different way to fulfill your needs.

Comment: OK, i just update with SQL fiddle.

Comment: Company Name? Where is that field in the fiddle? Your question is all over the place.

Comment: @JohnJoseph i use another simpler sample in the Fiddle, so now Room Name = Company Name.

Comment: Your question is tagged with Microsoft `sql-server`, yet your fiddle is for `mysql`. Please confirm or update your question tags.

Comment: @Sander Sorry just update the tag. Actually my app supports multiple DB engines. Either one will help, I will convert it to other DB engines. thanks.

Comment: @Jack, Can a product have multiple rooms ? And if yes how do you want them to display ?

Comment: A product can go to any rooms but each order can only has 1 room or no room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the requirements, I have taken the example query from fiddle link and could come up with below solution.

I am and not sure how we can take it from first union but certainly using `analytical function` which helps to read values of previous rows or within a window kind of we can achieve the same.

Considering an order have only one room , after the union we can check using `lag` if the `current row order id` matches with its `previous row order id` and then in the second step we use `first_value` to get the `room_number` for the same product by defining the partition and most importantly the `order by` clause.

```
select m.id AS 'Order ID'
      ,total AS 'Total'
      ,case 
        when m.id = lag(m.id) 
              over (partition by m.id
                    order by m.id,if(room_name is not null,1,2)
                   )
            and room_name is null
        then first_value(room_name)
             over (partition by m.id
                   order by m.id
                   ,if(room_name is not null,1,2)
                  )
       else
         room_name
       end AS 'Room Name'
      ,item_id AS 'Item ID'
      ,row_type AS 'Row Type'
  from
(
 select m.id AS 'ORDER_ID' 
       ,room_name  AS 'ROOM_NAME'
       ,null AS 'Item_ID'
       ,'From Details' AS 'Row_Type'
   from orders_master m 
   left join order_details d 
          on m.id = d.order_id
   left join store_rooms r 
          on d.room_id =r.id
  Where room_id is not null
union all
 select m.id AS 'ORDER_ID'
       ,null  AS 'ROOM_NAME'
       ,item_id AS 'Item_ID'
       ,'From Inventory' AS 'Row_Type'
 from orders_master m 
 left join order_inventory i ON m.id = i.order_id 
 Where item_id IS not null
) as u
inner join orders_master m  
        on m.id = u.order_id 
order by m.id, room_name, item_id;
```

Hope it goes with the actual query at end.

***EDIT:- Changed query considering OP is older than  MySQL 8.0 but in think this would be better than using analytic function***

I used max to fetch the room_name considering one order_id will have one room associated with it.

```
select m.id AS 'Order ID'
      ,total AS 'Total'
      ,case 
        when room_name is null
        then (select max(room_name) 
                from store_rooms r
                join order_details d
                  on d.room_id =r.id
               where d.order_id = m.id
             )
       else
         room_name
       end AS 'Room Name'
      ,item_id AS 'Item ID'
      ,row_type AS 'Row Type'
  from
(
 select m.id AS 'ORDER_ID' 
       ,room_name  AS 'ROOM_NAME'
       ,d.room_id as room_id
       ,null AS 'Item_ID'
       ,'From Details' AS 'Row_Type'
   from orders_master m 
   left join order_details d 
          on m.id = d.order_id
   left join store_rooms r 
          on d.room_id =r.id
  Where room_id is not null
union all
 select m.id AS 'ORDER_ID'
       ,null  AS 'ROOM_NAME'
       ,null as room_id
       ,item_id AS 'Item_ID'
       ,'From Inventory' AS 'Row_Type'
 from orders_master m 
 left join order_inventory i ON m.id = i.order_id 
 Where item_id IS not null
) as u
inner join orders_master m  
        on m.id = u.order_id 
order by m.id, room_name, item_id;
```

Comment: @Jack, Did it not fit to your requirement ?

Comment: hi, i tried the query in Sqlfiddler but i got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over (partition by m.id order by m.id,if(room_name is not nu' at line 5.

i continue trying many ways using ur concept, but still no luck.

Comment: May I know the mySql version of yours ?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2012 and above, MySQL v5.6 and above.

Comment: I edited my answer Kindly check if it fits to your requirement

Comment: Analytical function will only work from MySQL 8.0 but however the max solution ( if at all meets your requirements) should work with all versions I hope

Comment: Yay, it seems working, IN the same time i tried to remove the IF statements from your previous query, the syntax error are gone. let me test again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: normally i use limit  N for mysql / TOP N for SQL SERVER.

Comment: You mean to get the `max` ? If yes then it's up to you. I really don't know if it has any benefit here because of oreder_id in the where clause.